# Seeing significantly more number of calls to a certain function when run on Cortex-A9 as compared to Cortex-A15

Tags: c#

I own MS Surface and Samsung Ativ Tab. I had run the touchXPRT benchmark on both of them and analyzed the performance. I found that during encoding and decoding of image (using windows.graphics.imaging library, C#), there is a function (XYZW_YZXW_32bpp_NEON) that has the major usage during this process. On Ativ it shows 32 calls to this function and on Surface it shows 192 calls. (6 fold difference). I want to analyze this further and find out why is it happening. The krait CPU (on Ativ) is very much similar to cortex-A15 and Surface has Cortex-A9(tegra 3). There may be a difference in NEON Architecture. How do i firm it up and say that NEON is indeed responsible for this. Are there any tests that i can run to confirm this ? I dont have any base in NEON and i need help on this.

The code for touchXPRT and the underlying OS is same.
Thanks